# Custom Css class in confluence

Tags: html, css, confluence

I want to apply custom css class to the HTML tags in confluence. I tried adding css class in HTML macro as well as in css Macro. but the style is reflecting only in the preview, when i save and view the page style is not available, any advice

**HTML Macro:**

```
 <head>
      <style>
        .myClass {
          padding: 18px;
          background-color: Grey;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="myClass">
        <p>Answer will be posted here.</p>
      </div>
    </body>
```

**Css Macro**

```
.myClass{
  padding:  18px;
  background-color: Grey;

}
```

Preview
[image]

When i save and publish

[image]

Comment: Is Custom CSS enabled in your admin settings?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .myClass {
      padding: 18px;
      background-color: Grey;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="myClass">
    <p>Answer will be posted here.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/confluence-cloud/docs/what-are-macros/

Comment: i see this is exactly same as my question, Can i know what is the fix. And was this working in Confluence page ?

Comment: this may helps https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Styling-content-does-not-work/qaq-p/528630

Comment: thanks i checked , its not working, they have applied styles on html tags not on custom class name

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Simply get rid of the head section and try the below code:

```html
<body>
   <style>
      .myClass {
          padding: 18px;
          background-color: Grey;
      }
   </style>
   <div class="myClass">
      <p>Answer will be posted here.</p>
   </div>
</body>
```